# Wondering where the image is being pulled

Tags: php, css

I am new to css and coding, but I am wondering in the below code where it is pulling the imiage from the post. I dont want this page pulling images...it is pulling imiage from blog post and pages...is there a code I can place to make sure it does not pull the image?

thanks

```
<style>
    #para1{ text-align:center;}

    .bdr_blb{ 
        border:#000000 solid 4px;
        height:70px;
        background:#cccccc;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:14px; font-weight:700;}

    .light32{ font-size:32px;}

    .bggrey{ background:#cccccc;}

    .light18{ font-size:18px;}

    #bedroom4{
        background:#cccccc;
    }

    .heading_div{float:left;}

    .entry-content{float:left;}

    .thumnail_col ul li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .thumnail_col ul li img{background:none; border:none;}

</style>

?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="" role="main">
            <?php $args = array( 'category_name' => 'lease', 'orderby' => 'title' ,'order' => 'ASC' );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        if ($count==1)
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                       <td><div class="lease">
                            <div class="heading_div"><h2 class="entry-title"><strong><u>
                        <?php
                                                    echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/lease/'.$loop->post->post_name.'" target="_blank">'.$loop->post->post_title.'</a>';
                        ?>
                        </u></strong></div></h2>
                            <div class="entry-content">
                                <div class="desc">
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                        </div>

                        </div></div></td>
                        <?php
                        if($count==$number_of_columns)
                        {
                        echo "</tr>"; 
                        $count=0;
                        }   
                        $count++;

                        endwhile;
                    ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: What image? The only reference to images I can see there is in the CSS line `.thumnail_col ul li img{background:none; border:none;}` but that doesn't specify an image. And what do you mean by "pulling the image"?

Comment: there is no image on here at all just a background color of #cccccc on #bedroom4

Comment: From the blog post itself? i.e. `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: yes it is pulling image from blog post and pages...how do I stop that...is there a code I can place in here to make sure that it does not import the image

Comment: After you locate the definition of the function `the_content()`, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find where the function `the_content();` is defined.  Somewhere, look for:

```
function the_content()
```

Inside of that function definition is *possibly* code that echo's out an `<img>` tag.  Delete or comment out that portion of the code.  Until we see the definition of that function though, we cannot be sure of other consequences of modifying it.

**UPDATE**

This won't prevent the image from being loaded by the browser, but *will* prevent it from being actually *displayed* by the browser.  It's easier than tracking down the function definition to modify PHP.

Inside the `<style>` tag at the top of your posted code above, add this (it can go anywhere in there):

```
.entry-content img {display: none;}
```

This simply tells the CSS no to show the image even though the browser has downloaded it.

Comment: This is the page it is pulling it from...i could not find the_content anywhere?

Comment: it is pulling from a single post under a catagory...but i have looked every where for the function...any suggestion where something like that might be located?

Comment: @phill Look in the page you've posted above for `include()` `include_once()` `require()` or `require_once()` and then locate the files those includes point to. The function must be defined somewhere in one of them.

Comment: ok i found this in the loop <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
   </div><!-- .entry-content -->
  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: i keep coming across this entry-content code...it is everywhere...I jst found this---}
#top_img .entry-content{

 float:left;
 width:221px;
 clear:none;
 padding:0px;

Comment: OHHHH did not know i was suppose to do that...i need 15 more reputationm then i will